# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot. I'm Creating a Simple SpringBoot Application with Gradle Project. I created two models. When I run the application it shows the error like this.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.apache.tomcat.jni.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.apache.tomcat.jni.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.apache.tomcat.jni.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.apache.tomcat.jni.User


> Task :bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
        VirtualDoctorApplication.class,
        Jsr310JpaConverters.class
})
public class VirtualDoctorApplication {

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VirtualDoctorApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
```

And this is my build.gradle code:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0")
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

Project Structure[image]

Comment: What is your package structure and where is componentscan?

Comment: @mallikarjun I updated my post with structure

Comment: as mentioned in the bellow answer comment you might be using wrong import in in your UserRepository, Look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.apache.tomcat.jni.User
```

This means your JPA provider does not consider `org.apache.tomcat.jni.User` to be a JPA entity. Most probably this means that you need to modify your

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
        VirtualDoctorApplication.class,
        Jsr310JpaConverters.class
})
```

annotation to include at least one class in the same package as `org.apache.tomcat.jni.User` in the `basePackageClasses` attribute. The quick and dirty way to test that would be:

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
        VirtualDoctorApplication.class,
        Jsr310JpaConverters.class,
        org.apache.tomcat.jni.User.class
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Still, I'm facing the same error

Comment: As per your project structure it looks like you are referencing a wrong `User` class somewhere. You are referencing `org.apache.tomcat.jni.User`, but you should be referencing `com.freshworks.VirtualDoctor.model.User`. Search in your code for `org.apache.tomcat.jni.User` and substitute by `com.freshworks.VirtualDoctor.model.User`.

Comment: Strictly as a style advice, I would not use package names starting with a capital letter, it makes you think it is a class name instead of a package name. So I would use `com.freshworks.virtualdoctor` as your base package name

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved my problem. And hereafter I won't use a capital letter in the package name. Thanks for your valuable advice.